# factoring question $2(3x + 4)^2 + 2(2x + 3)3 (3x + 4) $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am looking over precalculus problems for the summer, and saw a factoring problem that I wasn't sure of.

How would you factor $2(3x + 4)^2 + (2x + 3) \cdot 2(3x + 4) \cdot 3$ step by step?   Wolfram alpha is giving me $2(3x+4)(9x+13)$.  For some reason i'm not getting this.

Comment: This site has a really nice equation editor. Please use it. :)

Comment: 1st step --- factor out the $2(3x+4)$.

Comment: I believe the last expression is ** 3, not * 3? Oh, maybe it's (2x + 3) ** 2 too...

Comment: @Tunococ it should be $*3$ since the entire equation is quadratic.

Comment: Aah. I must not have seen that requirement in the question. (I still don't...)

Comment: @Tunococ Actually there isn't! :P I'm just guessing the input into wolframalpha is right, since it has a display which should allow OP to check the input, so it should be fair to say it is what OP intended.

Comment: @BlackAdder I tend to assume that the OP is completely unaware of the mistakes. If the problem is written as it's supposed to be, those $2$ and $3$ should be exponents. (The first factor of $2$ was written in front of the parentheses.) But well, it's just my guesswork.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: Can you see the common factor? The common factor is $2(3x+4)$.

So, use the following: $ba+ca=a(b+c)$ and perhaps you can find the answer.

Edit: Notice that our equation is $2(3x+4)^2 +2(2x+3)3(3x+4)=2(3x+4)^2 + 6(2x+3)(3x+4)$. SO, the common factor is $2(3x+4)$ and hence we can write the equation as
$$2(3x+4)\cdot(3x+4)+2(3x+4)\cdot3(2x+3)$$
So, $a=2(3x+4),b=(3x+4),c=3(2x+3)$.

Comment: So I have 2(3x+4)[(3x+4)+1]*3(2x+3) I'm not sure what the next step is.  Btw I'm not sure where to find the equation editor.

Comment: @ray Don't worry about the equation editor at the moment. Hope my updated answer helps.

Answer (score 1):

We have our expression to factor:
$$2(3x+4)^2+2(2x+3)3(3x+4)$$
**Step 1: Simplify the equation as much as possible.** We can simplify the last term by multiplying the $2$ and $3$ to get $6$.
$$2(3x+4)^2+6(2x+3)(3x+4)$$
**Step 2: Identify the common factor.** Do you see we have a common factor $2(3x+4)$? We can factor this out to make the expression easier to factor.
$$2(3x+4)[(3x+4)+3(2x+3)]$$
**Step 3: Expand the terms in the second factor and simplify.**
$$2(3x+4)(3x+4+6x+9)$$
$$2(3x+4)(9x+13)$$
**Step 4: Look for any ways to simplify further.** We cannot simplify the expression any further, so our final answer is:
$$\displaystyle \boxed{2(3x+4)^2+2(2x+3)3(3x+4)=2(3x+4)(9x+13)}$$

---

**Alternative way to factor:**
We have our equation to factor:
$$2(3x+4)^2+2(2x+3)3(3x+4)$$
**Step 1: Simplify the expression as much as possible.** We can simplify the last term by multiplying the $2$ and the $3$ to get $6$.
$$2(3x+4)^2+6(2x+3)(3x+4)$$
**Step 2: Expand the expression.**
$$2(3x+4)^2+6(2x+3)(3x+4)$$
$$=2(9x^2+24x+16)+6(6x^2+8x+9x+12)$$
$$=18x^2+48x+32+6(6x^2+17x+12)$$
$$=18x^2+48x+32+36x^2+102x+72$$
$$=54x^2+150x+104$$
**Step 3: Identify the common factor.** Do you see we have a common factor $2$? We can factor this out to make the expression easier to factor.
$$2(27x^2+75x+52)$$
**Step 4: Factor the expression inside the brackets.** We want to multiply the coefficient of the $x^2$ term and $52$, and find two factors of the product that add up to $75$. $27\times 52=1404$. We need to find two factors of $1404$ that add up to $75$. After listing out the factors of $1404$ and testing them, I have found out that the two factors that add up to $72$ are $36$ and $39$. Now we can rewrite our expression as:
$$2(27x^2+36x+39x+72)$$
$$=2[9x(3x+4)+13(3x+4)]$$
Factoring by grouping yields:
$$2(9x+13)(3x+4)$$
**Step 5: Look for any ways to simplify further.** We cannot simplify the expression any further, so our final answer is:
$$\displaystyle \boxed{2(3x+4)^2+2(2x+3)3(3x+4)=2(9x+13)(3x+4)}$$

Comment: Excellent answer. I'm now a little embarrassed. :P +1

Answer (score 0):

*Option 1*:
If the expression is
$$
  A = 2(3x+4)^2 + (2x+3)^2 (3x+4)^3
$$
the common factor is $(3x +4)^2$ and you can write the expression as
$$
  A = (3x+4)^2\left[2 + (2x+3)^2 (3x+4)\right]
$$

*Option 2*:
If the expression is
$$
  B = 2(3x+4)^2 + [2(2x+3)][3(3x+4)]
$$
you can reorder it as
$$
  B = 2(3x+4)^2 + [2(3x+4)][3(2x+3)]
$$
in which case the common factor is $2(3x+4)$ and you have
$$
 \begin{align}
  B &= 2(3x+4)\left[(3x+4) + 3(2x+3)\right] \\
    & = 2(3x+4)\left[3x+4+6x+9\right] \\
    & = 2(3x+4)(9x+13)
 \end{align}
$$

P.S. Not sure how much homework help is acceptable but if something helps the student understand what's going on, why not.  Also, is there a WYSIWYG math editor here?